# Handling async in Clojure

Tags: asynchronous, clojure, clojurescript

I've defined myself a function for caching requests and their responses in a browser environment; I'm using ClojureScript.

```
(defn make-requester [namespace time-limit fun]
  (fn [cont & params]
    (let [cache (ls/get-item namespace)
          key (pr-str params)]
      (if
        (and
          (contains? cache key)
          (time/fresh? time-limit (:time (get cache key))))
        (cont (:value (get cache key)))
        (apply fun
               (concat [(fn [value]
                          (let [time (time/get-time)
                                updated (assoc cache key {:value value :time time})]
                            (ls/set-item namespace updated)
                            (cont value)))]
                       params))))))
```

Where
`ls/get-item`, `ls/set-item` are just getting/setting items in the local storage
and the `time/` functions do what they say. The `http/` functions are from the [cljs-http](https://github.com/r0man/cljs-http) module.

Example of using this:

```
(def get-status
  (make-requester
    "status"
    30000 ; 30 seconds
    (fn [cont url params]
      (go
        (cont (:body (<! (http/get url params))))))))

(get-status
  println
  "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1"
  {:with-credentials? false})
```

This is the first time I'm doing any async operations in ClojureScript and I'd like to improve the code in any way. Can the async bit be improved? Can the `apply` bit be improved? Is there no spread `...` shorthand? Is this the correcy way to serialzie/deserialize clojure data structures? Is the code Clojure-y enough?

Comment: Could you please include your imports or specify what libraries `ls` and `time` stand for?

Comment: @Phrancis They are described in text, right below the first code block.